Difference between a specific time and Now in dart?
I want a timer to count up (or down) from current time (Now) to a specific time in dart.
example:
Specific time: 15:46:49 | current time: 13:35:11 | duration: -02:11:39. Now I want a timer that counts from the specific to current.

You can use CountdownTimer from quiver for the timer
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.timestamp();
DateTime futureTime = DateTime.utc(currentTime.year, currentTime.month, currentTime.day, 15, 46, 49);
Duration timerDuration = futureTime.difference(currentTime);

CountdownTimer countDownTimer = new CountdownTimer(
  timerDuration,
  new Duration(seconds: 1),
);

var sub = countDownTimer.listen(null);
sub.onData((timer) {
  setState(() {
    remaining = timer.remaining;
    // derive hour minute and second - and display
  });
});

sub.onDone(() {
  print("Done");
  sub.cancel();
});


Mr. @Slashbin there is no path for CountdownTimer in quiver package and where is  remaining declaration?

@SulaimanFazli Add this to pubspec.yaml   quiver: ^3.2.1 and import will be this ->
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';

Mr. @Slashbin I have find if what you written, but this is not working current time: 2024-07-29 14:51:47.593888 future time, future time: 2024-07-29 18:57:00.000Z, Timer duration: 8:35:12.406112. This is wrong because the difference between current and future time is based on this information 04:06:12. but this is showing 8:35:12. Why? what is the reason? I cannot find it. But one thing in here the countdown timer is working.

this is because one of the time is in UTC and another in your time zone. Probably you are using Datetime.now() for the current Time or you may not be on newer Dart version. As per documentation =>   @Since("3.0")
DateTime.timestamp() : this._nowUtc();
